# Currency code to currency symbol mapping

Tags: java, currency

Good day,
in database there is table with houses for sale records. For each house record there is currency code (in ISO 4217 format) field. Is it possibly to somehow get currency symbol from that code so I could use it on presentation side ?

Thank you.

P.S. Was trying to resolve that problem setting Currency object (created by Currency.getInstance(currencyCode)) into DecimalNumberFormat setCurrency method and then format value I needed to display, but formatted value  still without currency symbol.

Comment: There is a better API for working with Money and Currencies http://javamoney.org

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `Currency` object's [getSymbol](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getSymbol()) method.

What symbol is used depends on the Locale which is used
See  [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mer08133/) and [this.](http://developers.sun.com/dev/gadc/technicalpublications/articles/java1.4currency.html)

**Update, Jan 2016:**
The links are now dead. But they were specific to Java 1.4/5 so not really relevant anymore. More details on currency formatting can be found in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html. The links can be found on the WayBackEngine though.

Comment: I tried to use getSymbol for USD then return is dollar sign (correct) but if I use EUR or DKK as currency code then the result is EUR or DKK http://ideone.com/ehmlP

Comment: What symbol is used depends on the Locale which is used. See articles in my (updated) answer

Comment: As I understood if I want to show appropriate currency symbol I need to keep Locale to format value in type I need am I right  (For example to correctly show GBP currency symbol I need to have GBP currency mapped for example on Locale.UK) ?

Comment: @Nivas Sorry for digging this one up, but links are not valid anymore, so answer doesn't have much sense right now.

Comment: @zubergu they were specific to Java 1.4/5 so not really relevant anymore. More details on currency formatting can be found in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html. The links can be found on the WayBackEngine though.

Answer (score 16):

@artjomka

I was able to reproduce your problem by setting my default locale to Latvia

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("lv","LV"));
Currency c  = Currency.getInstance("EUR");
System.out.println(c.getSymbol());
```

This gave me the output of "EUR".

However, by leaving setting my locale to Uk (already my default) I get the symbol for the Euro(€).

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.UK);
Currency c  = Currency.getInstance("EUR");
System.out.println(c.getSymbol());
```

Comment: Nivas edited his answer whilst I writing mine. His linked articles should see you right.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Currency class and DecimalFormat class for achieve your requirement.
In following example, # represents number and ¤  represents currency symbol, you can find relevant format parameters in java API doc for [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class.

```
        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance("USD");

        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#¤");
        decimalFormat.setCurrency(currency);
        System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(234));
```

Comment: As Nivas said, you can directly get relevant symbol using     getSymbol() method of Currency class and can append it separately to the number too.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `Currency.getSymbol(Locale)` rather than `Currency.getSymbol()` (without a locale object). Setting the default locale gives you the behavior that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Never blindly append currency symbols (that assumes that append is the locale-appropriate position of the currency symbol).  I18n-unsafe practice. Same with the "#¤" string (for locales with prefix currency symbol, this is incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

There is a code-Snippet in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15343675/702345

But be careful:

- One Currency can have multiple symbols. E.g.: USD has also the Symbol "US$" for Local "es_US" (at least on Java8, Win7 on my VM)
- Difference Currencies can have the same symbols, e.g.: USD, AUD