# Not getting currency symbols for specific Locale

Tags: java, localization, locale, currency

I am trying to get the symbols of the currencies based on their Locale. But instead of returning a symbol, it is returning the code. I have a snippet:

```
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CurrencyFormat
{
  public void displayCurrencySymbols() 
  {
   Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.US); 
   System.out.println("United States: " + currency.getSymbol());
  } 
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new CurrencyFormat().displayCurrencySymbols();
  }
}
```

For **Locale.US** it is giving symbol `$` but If I replace

```
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.US);
```

with

```
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
```

Then instead of symbol it is giving the country code. Why is this and how we can get the symbols?

**EDIT :** After looking some answer I would like to clear that setting some specific default local is not a solution as **I need all the avalaible sign displayed at once**.

e.g.

```
 Locale.setDefault(Locale.UK);
```

will give me the euro sign but for doller it will give the code instead of doller sign($).

Comment: I get `USD` rather than a `$`, using the latest Java 7 on Windows 7. My default locale is British, however. For Germany I see a Euro sign and for UK I see a pound sign.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: If I set `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);`, I get the same results as you.

Comment: Same with me, I get `USD` for locale US and `€` for GERMANY. I'm sitting at a Mac with german settings. (And for UK, I get `GBP`. Code executed on eclipse Juno SR1)

Comment: @JonSkeet: its Java 1.6

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, *precisely*? Perhaps you just want to pass the same locale into `getSymbol`, to get "the representation that someone of that locale would use for their own currency"?

Comment: @RamDuttShukla For clarification, when you say "*it is giving the country code*", what do you mean exactly? Do you see `EUR` for Germany?

Comment: @JonSkeet : I have editted my question to be more clear

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes I see EUR for Germany. JPY for JAPAN and so on

Comment: @RamDuttShukla: Right. You should edit the question again, as "EUR" is not a *country* code...

Comment: If you really, really, really want the native symbol for each currency, then you can say `String symbolFor(Locale l) {return Currency.getInstance(l).getSymbol(l);}`. But you almost certainly don't want to.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

hi please try the following code

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class CurrencyExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         Utils.getCurrencySymbol( Currency.getInstance(Locale.US).getCurrencyCode());
         Utils.getCurrencySymbol(Currency.getInstance(Locale.JAPAN).getCurrencyCode());
         Utils.getCurrencySymbol(Currency.getInstance(Locale.UK).getCurrencyCode());
         Utils.getCurrencySymbol("INR");
    }
}

class Utils{
      public static SortedMap<Currency, Locale> currencyLocaleMap;
      static {
          currencyLocaleMap = new TreeMap<Currency, Locale>(new Comparator<Currency>() {
            public int compare(Currency c1, Currency c2){
                return c1.getCurrencyCode().compareTo(c2.getCurrencyCode());
            }
        });
        for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
             try {
                 Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
             currencyLocaleMap.put(currency, locale);
             }catch (Exception e){
         }
        }
    }

    public static String getCurrencySymbol(String currencyCode) {
        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);
        System.out.println( currencyCode+ ":-" + currency.getSymbol(currencyLocaleMap.get(currency)));
        return currency.getSymbol(currencyLocaleMap.get(currency));
    }
}
```

The output of above program is like that:

```
USD:-$
JPY:-￥
GBP:-£
INR:-Rs.
```

Comment: One Currency can have multiple symbols. E.g.: USD has also the Symbol "US$" for Local "es_US" (Java8, Win7 on my VM).
And difference Currencies can have the same symbols, e.g.: USD, AUD

Answer (score 11):

You are seeing what Java thinks users in your default locale *expect* to see for a currency symbol. This is also confirmed by the Javadocs for `getSymbol()`:

> Gets the symbol of this currency for the default locale. For example, for the US Dollar, the symbol is "$" if the default locale is the US, while for other locales it may be "US$". If no symbol can be determined, the ISO 4217 currency code is returned.

By changing your default locale:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.UK); // e.g.
```

You can experiment to prove this for yourself. (*Note: I'm not suggesting this is a solution, merely an opportunity for you to check what other locales see*).

I would recommend you stick with whatever Java thinks is appropriate for your default locale - I'm sure it's understandable by your users.

---

It might seem attractive to seek the "normal" currency symbol for every currency, however take a look at the following currency list: http://www.xe.com/symbols.php.

Look how many countries recognise their currency with a `$` symbol. Egypt also uses the British pound symbol (`£`). The whole idea behind the locale currency symbol is to give you a string that users in *your locale* will understand.

Comment: setting Default local to UK is giving me the EURO sign but now I am not getting the $ sign.

Comment: The default locale may very well *not* be the locale of the user though - think webapp...

Comment: @JonSkeet But that's always going to be a challenge for webapps. Even down to what the time should be considered to be. I would have thought most webapps were either fixed to a locale (in a "deal with it, user" sense) or would allow the user to select a locale, timezone, etc.

Comment: Anyway, that seems to be wrong approach to get the `$` sign for the US currency on *all* machines. But good to know/to remember. If we rely on the wrong assumption that we get the `$` that way, software may fail on other machines.

Comment: @Andreas_D For many countries, `$` means something else anyway. In Australia, for example, or Hong Kong.

Comment: @DuncanJones : I have editted my question to get clear input from you. THanks

Comment: Yes, sure, you're right. `$` is ambigious. So there *is* a good reason to use the currency symbol of the actual locale. And another good reason to *not* change the Locale just for getting `$` for US currency an all machines ;)

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution, based on [Amrit Raj Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2153710/amrit-raj-sharma)'s answer:

Just add the locale as a parameter to the `getSymbol()` method.

So, change your code to:

```
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CurrencyFormat
{
  public void displayCurrencySymbols() 
  {
   Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.US); 
   System.out.println("United States: " + currency.getSymbol(Locale.US));
  } 
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new CurrencyFormat().displayCurrencySymbols();
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for other currencies. E.g. it will display "COP" for colombian peso instead of "$"