# Not able to get correct Currency symbol for countries

Tags: java

I tried with java.text.NumberFormat.For denmark english, it gave me 'DKK' .But i need 'kr'.

```
Locale denmark = new Locale("en","DK");
NumberFormat denmarkFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(denmark);
System.out.println("Denmark: " + denmarkFormat.format(num));
```

I tried with java.util.Currency.getSymbol(). For denmark english,it also gave me 'DKK' only.

```
Locale denmark = new Locale("en","DK");
Currency curr = Currency.getInstance(denmark);
String symbol = curr.getSymbol(denmark);
```

(OR)

I can get all my custom currency symbols in jsp but if i pass that symbol to java,it is not able to get it properly.For UK,'£' symbol passed from jsp is received as `&pound;` in java. This is how i get it in java,

```
String Currency=(String)pageContext.getRequest().getAttribute("CurrencySymbol");
```

Getting solution for anyone of these problems will be great.Thanks in advance.

I need the below currency symbols,

```
USA-$
CA-$
CN-¥
PL-zł
TR-TRY
NL-EUR
SE-kr
DK-kr
FI-EUR
AU-$
DE-EUR
CH-CHF
GB-£
IT-EUR
AT-EUR
FR-EUR
ES-EUR
BE-EUR
IE-EUR
PT-EUR
NO-kr
HK-$
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106484/not-getting-currency-symbols-for-specific-locale ?

Comment: Well, English is not a native language of Denmark. Try with `da_DK`.

Comment: Thanks for providing me the link for solution .Can i get the solution for my second question because this will be easy to implement than writing a big piece of code in java

Comment: thanks everyone for the solutions.
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3(Currency) is the solution for my second question