# Use "R" instead of "ZAR" for South African Currency

Tags: java, android, currency-formatting

How can I use "R" for currency when the locale is set to South Africa?

Currently it shows "ZAR" and I need it to show "R" instead.

I have tried:

```
final Currency curr = Currency.getInstance("ZAR");
final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());
nf.setCurrency(curr);
final String value = nf.format(12345.67);
```

and then once all this is done, I replaced ZAR with R using.replace();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a great example that works:

```
      public static SortedMap<Currency, Locale> currencyLocaleMap;
  static {
    currencyLocaleMap = new TreeMap<Currency, Locale>(new Comparator<Currency>() {
      public int compare(Currency c1, Currency c2){
        return c1.getCurrencyCode().compareTo(c2.getCurrencyCode());
      }
    });
    for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
      try {
        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
        currencyLocaleMap.put(currency, locale);
      }catch (Exception e){
      }
    }
  }

  public static String getCurrencySymbol(String currencyCode) {
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);
    System.out.println( currencyCode+ ":-" + currency.getSymbol(currencyLocaleMap.get(currency)));
    return currency.getSymbol(currencyLocaleMap.get(currency));
  }
```

from here: [Not getting currency symbols for specific Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15343675/4578531)

Answer (score 4):

The `NumberFormat` class formats the number based on the locale that is passed as a param. If the locale is for South Africa (`new Locale("en", "ZA")`) then the number will appear correctly: R 12,345.67

```
final Currency curr = Currency.getInstance("ZAR");
final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "ZA"));
nf.setCurrency(curr);
final String value = nf.format(12345.67);
System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Build your own `NumberFormat` class (that extends Java's), and implement your own version of `format`; calling the base class function for all currencies other than `ZAR`.

The approach you're currently taking will tend to lead to a lot of repeated (and unencapsulated) code.

Comment: Thanks, are there any libraries out there that could do this already?

Comment: It's a rather specific (and, dare I say, idiosyncratic) requirement, so I doubt it. My approach is only a dozen or so lines of code.