# currency issue on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

On my localhost I am using this function to give me a value in currency format

```
  const currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-ZA", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "ZAR",
    currencyDisplay: "symbol",
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  });
```

This works as expected. However, after deploying to Heroku instead of the output being:

```
R 6,500.00
```

it is

```
 ZAR 6,500.00
```

is this a heroku thing or issue with the code?

Comment: Maybe it is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337115/use-r-instead-of-zar-for-south-african-currency

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use "R" instead of "ZAR" for South African Currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337115/use-r-instead-of-zar-for-south-african-currency)

Comment: I don't know, that is JAVA code

Comment: I tried adding this as well but still doesn't work `currencyDisplay: "symbol",`

Answer (score -1):

According to [NodeJS docs](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html):

> Node.js (and its underlying V8 engine) uses [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) to implement these features in native C/C++ code. The full ICU data set is provided by Node.js by default. However, due to the size of the ICU data file, several options are provided for customizing the ICU data set either when building or running Node.js.

So in short, Heroku NodeJS is missing full language support.

To solve that, you can install [full-icu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/full-icu) library and set `NODE_ICU_DATA` ENV variable in `start` command:

```
NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu node app.js
```

Check [Providing ICU data at runtime](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html#intl_providing_icu_data_at_runtime) for more information.