# getting currency symbol from local

Tags: java, localization

In my java code at one place Locale is being set(based on language). for exmample at any time Local object will be one of the followig.

```
{ Locale.GERMAN, Locale.FRENCH, Locale.JAPANESE, Locale.KOREAN, Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE,Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE, new Locale("es","") }
```

now the limitation is I can't change this part of code and can only utilize getter method to get the Locale.
I have to print "Currency Display Name". which I have tried by below methods

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(I18nUtil.getLocale()).getCurrency().getDisplayName();
Currency.getInstance(I18nUtil.getLocale()).getDisplayName();
```

The first one is giving `"Unknown currency"` and the sceond one is giving `"Null Pointer Exception"`.
I also tried providing hardcoded Locale ex. `Locale.FRANCE, Locale.CHINA`(country name) which is working fine. So my question is there any way to get Currency Display Name from the Locale which is set beased on language.
I would be really very thankful if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888991/currency-code-to-currency-symbol-mapping

Comment: Language may not be sufficient to obtain the currency you want, e.g. English is spoken in the US and UK, which covers more than one currency.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Thank you so much for your input. I also tried in many different ways and concluded that its not possible just with language

Comment: This is also my recollection from when I dealt with currencies.