# How to get currency symbol from Play Billing Library

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I use `Play Billing Library` and I have two `subscriptions` for one and three months. For a `3` month subscription, I want to display the price for `1` month.
For example, a `1` month subscription is `$1,50` and a `3` month subscription is `$3` (`$1` for a `1` month). But I have some problems with currencies.

This is a `code:`

```
long priceAmountMicros = skuDetails.getPriceAmountMicros(); //3000000
String priceCurrency = skuDetails.getPriceCurrencyCode(); //USD

float priceFloat = (float)priceAmountMicros / 3 / 1000000; //1
String price = new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(priceFloat);

Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(priceCurrency);
String symbolCurrency = currency.getSymbol();//$

textView.setText(price + " " + symbolCurrency); //1.00 $ or 70.00 руб
```

The code almost is working. **USD** converted to **$**. **EUR** converted to **£** and others. There are some problems with some currencies, for example, the Russian currency does not work. **RUB** converted to **руб**, but I expect **₽**

There is a standard method for getting the `price:`

```
String price = skuDetails.getPrice();//3 $ or 210 ₽
```

Am I doing something wrong? Could you help me please?

Comment: as i can see the library uses ISO 4217 so rouble symbol in ISO 4217 is руб

Comment: @bbadawee  If I get skuDetails.getPrice(); then it returns the price 210 ₽. But I need to divide this by 3 with currency ₽

Comment: I have the same problem. I will checking your question if you found out the problem

Comment: @TimWeb method currency.getSymbol() from java framework is buggy and does not work PROPERLY - for many currencies it is completely WRONG - for example for THAI baht it returns THB and not currency symbol ฿, as it should. And same for many other currencies, it seems quite random...

Comment: EUR is € and not £. £ is for GBP.

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3889573/6478047)

Answer (score 7):

You can use Currency class from java.util package

```
Currency.getInstance(sku.priceCurrencyCode).symbol
```

will give you the symbol for currency code

Answer (score 0):

One cannot assume that the currency symbol always would be to the left of the price.

Simply strip all numbers and decimal separators:

```
String symbol = skuDetails.getPrice().replaceAll("[\\d.,]", "");
```

However, the most easy might be:

```
textView.setText(skuDetails.getPrice());
```

I mean, why you even need the currency symbol?

Comment: Because we need modify the price (the number). For example I want to show monthly price for yearly subscription. I need divide price to 12 for that and display formatted result. Will your regex work for Arabic or Chinese numbers??

Answer (score 0):

getOriginalPrice() - returns the original price with additional currency formatting.

Comment: We need to modify the number and present formatted result. For example I need to show monthly price for yearly subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get the monthly price for an annual subscription. Don't use java currency class as it has issues with some currencies.

```
private fun getAnnualMonthlyPrice(skuDetails: SkuDetails): String {
    val re = Regex("[0-9.,]")
    val currency = re.replace(skuDetails.price, "")
    val priceMicro = skuDetails.priceAmountMicros / (1_000_000f * 12f)
    return "${currency}${"%.2f".format(priceMicro)}"
}
```